# How to find all occurances of a single quote not within a word with python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

> 'name': 'Janya's Thai Delight'

I want to replace all of the single quotes with double quotes as long as they are not surrounded on either side by letters. In other words, I want every single quote except the one in `Janya's` to become a double quote. I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

```
re_string = '\'(?![a-z])|\'(?=[a-z])'
re.sub(re_string, '"', "'name': 'Janya's Thai Delight'")
# results in:  "name": "Janya"s Thai Delight"
```

**Expected result:** `"name": "Janya's Thai Delight"`

Comment: So what's your expected result ?

Comment: @noob Expected result should be `"\"name\": \"Janya's Thai Delight \""`

Comment: That looks like it came from a dict, how did you end up with it in that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(?<![a-zA-Z])'|'(?![a-zA-Z])` and replace with `"`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])'` matches apostrophe not preceded by a letter.
- `'(?![a-zA-Z])` matches the apostrophe not followed by a letter.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR6pA5/1)**

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In that case regex could be modified but question would be what **something** would be there ? OP didn't specified anything. It seems he is only concerned with alphabets.