# Regex find incorrect "

Tags: regex, csv

i am trying to build an regex to find wrong " in an csv file:
for example

```
,"Nori",,,,,896282962,23.07.2013,,,,"Lady Love "Karo","w",
```

The `"` before Karo is wrong, but there can be multiple `"` inside a `,"",` column.
So every `,"` and `",` is correct but an `"` with leading or following char and no `,` before or after the char is incorrect.
Can anyone help me find the correct regex pattern?

Regards.

Comment: If I understand your question correct, you should be able to use negative lookbehinds and negative lookaheads for this.

Comment: [Similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439021/how-to-find-all-occurances-of-a-single-quote-not-within-a-word-with-python-regex/36439067#36439067).

Comment: Shouldn't CSV format allow double `"` inside a field to denote a literal `"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<!,|^)"(?!,|$)
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xH8kK5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!,|^)` : Negative lookbehind to check for `,` or start of the string
- `"` : Match quote
- `(?!,|$)` : Negative lookahead to check for `,` or end of the string