# How to remove single quotes only from ends of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, strip

I'm trying to take a dictionary:

```
{'company': 'BOOK TA .K (TAMAN DAYA) SDN BHD', 'date': '25/12/2018', 'address': 'NO.53 55,57 & 59, JALAN SAGU 18, TAMAN DAYA, 81100 JOHOR BAHRU, JOHOR.', 'total': '9.00'}
```

And try to remove quotes surrounding each key and value as follows (desired output):

```
{company:BOOK TA .K (TAMAN DAYA) SDN BHD, date:25/12/2018, address:NO.53 55,57 & 59, JALAN SAGU 18, TAMAN DAYA, 81100 JOHOR BAHRU, JOHOR., total:9.00}
```

The problem is that no matter which code I try (regex, strip, rstrip...), I end up snipping those single quotes that come in the middle (this is part of a large dataset and there are many cases in which the company and address fields have quotation marks as part of them ) I **cannot lose these embedded single quotes**, I must only get rid of those at the end. eg.

```
'Wendy's Stall' -> Wendy's Stall
```

is what I need,

**NOT**

```
'Wendy's Stall' -> Wendys Stall
```

I thought initially that this question is similar to what I need:
[Removing single quotes from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843353/removing-single-quotes-from-a-dictionary)
, but the problem is that they simply took integer representations of the value and got away with it as all values were numbers and not strings.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: One of the former solutions is `re.sub(r"\B'\b|\b'\B", "", text)`. There is also `re.sub(r"\b(')\b|'", r"\1", text)`. Also, see [How to find all occurances of a single quote not within a word with python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439021/how-to-find-all-occurances-of-a-single-quote-not-within-a-word-with-python-regex)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does not help because the OP asks for removing quotes from a `dic`, not from `string`.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary is actually a dictionary and not just a string that looks like a dictionary, you can simply convert it into a string that looks like you want:

```
d = {'company': 'Wendy\'s Stall', 'date': '25/12/2018', 'address': 'NO.53 55,57 & 59, JALAN SAGU 18, TAMAN DAYA, 81100 JOHOR BAHRU, JOHOR.', 'total': '9.00'}
s = "{"+", ".join(["{}:{}".format(k,v) for k,v in d.items()])+"}"
print(s)
```

Output:

```
{company:Wendy's Stall, date:25/12/2018, address:NO.53 55,57 & 59, JALAN SAGU 18, TAMAN DAYA, 81100 JOHOR BAHRU, JOHOR., total:9.00}
```

Side note: If your "dictionary" is a string, you can try to convert it into an actual dict either using JSON (if it's valid JSON) or using AST.

Comment: Your solution looses the option to `prettyprint` the key-value-pair line by line. So in my use case I stay with `prettyprint` and the quotes in key + value dict.